# ERROR use datename/datepart in R sqldf package

Tags: sql, r, sqldf

I have an error message when I running sqldf package for datename or datepart.
Here is the table I used.

```
Height Date
163  12/01/90
182  11/13/88
167   5/14/97
172   3/18/94
170  10/11/92 
185   7/15/90


expected_table <-sqldf("select 
               [Height],
               (datename(weekday,[Date])) AS [Day of Week]
               from table1

               ")

Error in sqliteSendQuery(con, statement, bind.data) : 
  error in statement: no such column: weekday
```

If not,does it have any way to get weekday from the [Date]?

Comment: This depends on what the underlying database is.  `datename()` is specific to SQL Server (actually T-SQL, so it works in Sybase as well).

Comment: That being said, please update your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it attached.

Comment: @GordonLinoff so datename() and datepart() are not available in sqldf?

Comment: @user3849475 . . . No. `datename()` and `datepart()` are not available in SQLite.  Read about what you can do here:  https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sqldf is a thin layer which passes the data and SQL statement to a back end of your choice.  The default back end is sqlite but it also supports H2, PostgreSQL and MySQL.  SQLite does not support `datename` but H2 does support `dayname`:

```
# reproducibly set up input data frame 
Lines <- "Height Date
163  12/01/1990
182  11/13/1988
167   5/14/1997
172   3/18/1994
170  10/11/1992 
185   7/15/1990"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
DF$Date <- as.Date(DF$Date, "%m/%d/%Y")  # Date class

library(RH2)  # if RH2 is loaded sqldf will automatically use H2 instead of sqlite
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select *, dayname(Date) Weekday from DF")
```

giving:

```
  Height       Date   Weekday
1    163 1990-12-01  Saturday
2    182 1988-11-13    Sunday
3    167 1997-05-14 Wednesday
4    172 1994-03-18    Friday
5    170 1992-10-11    Sunday
6    185 1990-07-15    Sunday
```

**Note:** Of course it is also easy to do this in straight R:

```
transform(DF, Weekday = format(Date, "%A"))
```

giving:

```
  Height       Date   Weekday
1    163 1990-12-01  Saturday
2    182 1988-11-13    Sunday
3    167 1997-05-14 Wednesday
4    172 1994-03-18    Friday
5    170 1992-10-11    Sunday
6    185 1990-07-15    Sunday
```

Comment: when I use transform(DF, Weekday = format(Date, "%A")) ,there is an error message: Error in format.default(structure(as.character(x), names = names(x), dim = dim(x),  : 
  invalid 'trim' argument

Comment: Start a new fresh session of R. Do not type anything into it.  Just copy and paste everything from `Lines <- ...` to `DF$Date <- as.Date(DF$Date, "%m/%d/%Y") ` to create the data frame and then copy and paste `transform(DF, Weekday = format(Date, "%A"))`

Comment: When I typing DF$Date <- as.Date(DF$Date, "%m/%d/%Y") ,all date changed to "0090-12-01","0088-11-13"

Comment: I just checked my data.I have two original datasets.One dataset date format "12/01/94" and the other data date format is "12/01/1994".One works.But "12/01/94" does not work.Thanks.

Comment: Read `?strptime` and note the difference between `%y` and `%Y`.